# Can't create new "Diagnostics with code fix" project! (Roslyn+VS2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, roslyn, diagnostics

After the [Roslyn SDK preview](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=52793) installation for *Visual Studio 2013*

1. *Roslyn SDK Project Templates.vsix*
2. *Roslyn Syntax Visualizer.vsix*
3. *Install Roslyn Preview into Roslyn Experimental Hive.exe*

in that order

**I am not able to create** a new project under Roslyn-> **Diagnostics with code fix**, I'm getting a warning message as shown below.

[image: The warning popup]

Comment: Have you installed the Visual Studio SDK?

Comment: You have to install the [Visual Studio 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this [CodePlex Issue](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/78),  you need to have the [VS SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758%5C) installed to use that template, since it creates a Visual Studio Extension (vsix).